# ffmpeg output in log file using C#

Tags: c#, logging, ffmpeg

This is a simple code to create ffmpeg log output in a file instead of console.

```
string fullPath = "d:";
string fileName= "wildlife.wmv";
string pathfile = "D:";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + fullPath + "\" + fileName + +\" 2> \"" + pathfile + "\ffmpeglog.log\"";

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start();
string output2 = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

But this code doesn't create an output log file wherein the same arrangements when used in command prompt it works. Can anybody help in this? what more needs to be done to get the output in the log file?

Regards
Arunava

Comment: Is your `fullPath` value Ok?

Comment: Try to read the arguments i bet the path is wrong

Comment: `"\ffmpeglog.log\""` wouldn't this have to be `"\\ffmpeglog.log\""` ?

Comment: Also `+"\" +filename + + \" 2 > \""` will result in `" +filename + + " 2 > "` right?

Comment: Try `"-i \"" + fullPath + "\"" + fileName + "\" 2> \"" + pathfile + "\\ffmpeglog.log\"";`

Comment: Tried with the above code but its not working. When we run ffmpeg with the same code we need to remove the final "\" after ffmpeglog.log to generate the log. 
When I am using
" -i \"d:\\wildlife.wmv 2> \"D:\\ffmpeglog.log\""
The log is not generating but cannot remove the "\" from the string since its throwing Newline constant error.
How can I use 
" -i \"d:\\wildlife.wmv 2> \"D:\\ffmpeglog.log""
instead of the previous code.